# Where are CUDA toolkit runtimes of pytorch and tensorflow, will they conflict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I found that we can just install `pytorch` or `tensorflow` using `pip` without CUDA-toolkit runtimes from nvidia or linux package manager.

So where is the runtime they use and will they conflict with each other?
for example, I have 5 python virtual environment:

```
pytorch==1.6+cu101
pytorch==1.7+cu110
conda pytorch==1.7 cudatoolkit=11.0
conda pytorch==1.6 cudatoolkit=10.2
tensorflow
```

Will they work together?
If not, where is the conflict and which runtime is shared by all of them?
If I want to use pytorch in different virtual environment, any suggestion for me to follow?

Comment: There is only one driver -- the NVIDIA driver for your GPU, and it must be new enough to be compatible with all the cudatoolkits you have installed if you want them all to work

Comment: @talonmies, maybe there is some mistake here, the driver I meant here is cuda-toolkit, for example: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads. Pytorch could use cuda without this one installed.

Comment: Please open the question. I updated it so its much clearer. he is asking for the runtimes and not drivers per say. the runtimes required are shipped with Pytorch and  thus you dont need to have cuda-toolkit installed previously. but you must have a working NVIDIA driver working already or you wont be able to run anything pytorchy! and no they wont conflict as far as I know.